# Is there any way to pass an argument to a pytest fixture?

Tags: pytest, pytest-django

I have a fixture and I want to pass a value for max_count from the test case to be used by fixture

```
@pytest.fixture
def new_instance_demo(instance_name, os_demo, config):

    instance = os_demo.create_server(
        instance_name,
        image=config.image.images_list[0],
        flavor=config.launch_instances.flavor,
        availability_zone=config.launch_instances.available_zone,
        network=config.network.external_network,
        wait=True,
        max_count,
    )
    yield instance
    os_demo.delete_server(instance_name)
```

I want to pass different values for **max_count** from the test cases , Is there any way pytest fixture allows that ?

Comment: This is a "code smell" in my opinion. You should invert the relationship and structure in a way that the test case gets the values from a fixture.

Answer (score 0):

This is addressed in the "[Parametrizing fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.3.x/how-to/fixtures.html#fixture-parametrize)" section of the pytest documentation. Your fixture can read a parameter from `request.param`, and you can use the `pytest.mark.parametrize` decorator in your tests to set the parameter value.

Here's a simple example:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(params=[1])
def example_fixture(request):
    yield request.param

def test_that_passes(example_fixture):
    assert example_fixture == 1

@pytest.mark.parametrize('example_fixture', [2])
def test_that_fails(example_fixture):
    assert example_fixture == 1
```

Your fixture would end up looking something like this:

```
@pytest.fixture(params=[1])
def new_instance_demo(request, instance_name, os_demo, config):
    instance = os_demo.create_server(
        instance_name,
        image=config.image.images_list[0],
        flavor=config.launch_instances.flavor,
        availability_zone=config.launch_instances.available_zone,
        network=config.network.external_network,
        wait=True,
        max_count=request.param,
    )
    yield instance
    os_demo.delete_server(instance_name)
```

And you would use it like this:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('new_instance_demo', [10])
def test_something(new_instance_demo):
    ...
```